# Evaluating log-likelihood of unseen data in rstan

Tags: r, bayesian, stan, rstan, log-likelihood

I understand I can calculate the log likelihood of each sample during sampling, e.g.

```
...

model {

  for (i in 1:N) {
    (y[i] - 1) ~ bernoulli(p[i, 2]);
  }

}

generated quantities {

  vector[N] log_lik;
  for (i in 1:N){
    log_lik[i] = bernoulli_lpmf((y[i] - 1) | p[i, 2]);
  }

}
```

After fitting, I can then extract log likelihood using the `loo` package:

```
log_lik_m <- extract_log_lik(stan_fit)
```

But I want to evaluate log likelihood of unseen data. This is possible in brms:

```
ll <- log_lik(fit_star, newdata = new_df)
```

But I would like to do this with `rstan`, since I can't easily define my model in brms (I am assuming).

For reference, I am trying to use Estimated LFO-CV to evaluate and compare my time-series model. 
(e.g. https://github.com/paul-buerkner/LFO-CV-paper/blob/master/sim_functions.R#L186)

(https://mc-stan.org/loo/articles/loo2-lfo.html)

Comment: One method is described in this post: https://medium.com/@alex.pavlakis/making-predictions-from-stan-models-in-r-3e349dfac1ed:  You can write another Stan program with only `data` and `generated quantities` blocks, where `data` contains the already estimated posterior distributions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the link from @dipetkov, I solved this myself. I didn't use the exact methods in the [link](https://medium.com/@alex.pavlakis/making-predictions-from-stan-models-in-r-3e349dfac1ed), but came up with an alternative. You can call stan functions from R to get it to compute log likelihood for your model, even with unseen data (and its very fast!).

First, I put everything in my `transformed parameters` block into a function in stan's `functions` block. Then, I created a second function that wraps the first function, and evaluates the log likelihood for given observations and provided parameter estimates (I then removed my `generated_quantities` block). `rstan` has a function `expose_stan_functions` which adds all functions in the stan `functions` block to the R environment.

You can then call the log likelihood function you made to evaluate your model with any observations (previously seen or unseen), along with a set of parameter estimates.

Comment: Would be better if you could attach your code.